# Unhandled exception at 0x7604c128 in CPP_TEST.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow

Tags: c++, c, malloc, free

Why this `stackover flow` is happening where as I am using `fflush` and `free` in my code.
Please help me.

```
using namespace std;

    struct abc{
        int x;int y;
        }abc;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct abc *xyz = (struct abc *) malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    xyz->x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", xyz->x);
    //system("pause");
        free(xyz);
     // xyz = NULL;
        fflush(stdout);
        _tmain(NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Edited Code:

```
xyz:
    struct abc *xyz = (struct abc *) malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    xyz->x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", xyz->x);
    //system("pause");

    free(xyz);
    xyz = NULL;
    fflush(stdout);
    goto xyz;
```

Comment: Well, what is that: `_tmain(NULL, NULL);` ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using malloc/free?

Comment: @Simon: Yes, I would like to allocate memory for struct and freeing the memory for the struct. and wanted to reallocate the same when program execution repeats.

Comment: If you put that code in a "normal" loop, you would only require a single `malloc()` and `free()` before and after the loop.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer: I have updated the code.Please have a look

Comment: Why would you use a goto instead of a loop?? You might wan't to ask another question telling what you are **actually trying to do**, as this question is (imho) answered.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer: Putting `for(;;){....}` is same as `label: .... goto label`. Don't u think so?

Comment: Yes, but that's considered very bad style. There are few cases where gotos are "accepted", replacing loops with gotos is not one of them ... Apart from that the code, from what I can tell, should run fine (forever ...), although I really can't tell what you are **actually trying to do**. Please accept your favourite answer and write a follow up question if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are unconditonally calling the `_tmain()` function from your `_tmain()` function, causing infinite recursion. Every call needs to allocate space on the stack (which is never freed), causing your StackOverflow exception. Take a look at e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) too fully understand the problem.

Apart from that, calling the `main()` function from your own code is ususally not a good idea, as its forbidden by the standard.

> §3.6.1.3: The function main shall not be used within a program.

Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Yes, but you are allocating memory on the stack, I will extend my answer.

Comment: I am working in a project where there is nearly a same type of code written.

Comment: Specify "nearly" ;) Calling the main function from your own program is unspecified behaviour. And infinite recursion will result in a stack overflow unless the compiler is able to transform it into a loop. But I wouldn't rely on either behaviour, as it might change from compiler to compiler.

Comment: It can't be anything else. If there is no condition to determine whether or not the recursive call will be done, you are definitely asking for a stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

The system needs memory for your variables on the stack, you allocated stack variables, those take up memory with every recursive call. Also it needs memory to store the return pointer as well with every recursive call.